# How do we stop or reduce P2P use of the guest Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, p2p, traffic-filtering

I support a small business' tech issues. Their guest Wi-Fi is important since they want people sitting around and consuming their product. We’re currently using a consumer-grade access point with DD-WRT.

Over the past months they've received many DMCA notices from their ISP for the downloading porn via P2P. We suspect a customer.

Is there a good way to stop (or significantly reduce) p2p on the guest wifi using dd-wrt? 
(focus narrowed in response to removal of previous question.)

Comment: Use a captive portal; block the typical ports used; even better only allow http and https

Comment: You will need to use a mandatory proxy or DPI filter. Blocking ports to only allow HTTP/S won't work.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq DPI filter?

Comment: @uSlackr: [Deep packet inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection)—you'd probably need some kind of UTM appliance, perhaps a [FortiWiFi](http://www.fortinet.com/products/fortiwifi/) gateway would help here? They aren't cheap, though, and you'll need an expensive subscription to keep them running.

Comment: At our business I've had good luck using opendns servers and blocking things like p2p sites/proxys and anything else I don't want going on here. I then have firewall rules set up in ddwrt so opendns is the only dns server that can be used. You can also block the common P2P ports. Maybe not "loop hole" perfect but it seems to work in my scenario.

Comment: The problem (which everybody seems to have missed) is BitTorrent trackers ARE HTTP, and practically always operate on port 80.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq what's the implication of the trackers being HTTP? Are they easier to block?

Comment: @uSlackr: No, it makes them impossible to block with port or firewall rules, hence why you need a proxy or DPI. As long as you allow web traffic, then you also allow BitTorrent tracker connections.

Comment: I've seen some thoughts that blocking web content containing "tracker" & "announce" might help.

Answer (score 1):

If the business only wants users trying their product on the guest WiFi, you could set up a basic captive portal that forwards users to their product's website/servers, and block all other traffic using the router's built-in filters if it has them.

There are several appliances you could purchase that would be more granular if they don't want to totally restrict the access. One I can think of is [Untangle](https://www.untangle.com/products/).

Comment: The goal is to allow them to use the wifi for everything - almost.  This is a tap room. We want folks to hang out.

Comment: @uSlackr I use untangle for my public WiFi APs in the convenience stores I work for. It's not free, but it's priced per app you use. Cheap if you only want the content control. You can install it on practically anything or buy one of their prebuilt appliances. https://www.untangle.com/ic-control/